# Rephrasing a sentence containing the word "chance"

Tags: sentence

Is it possible to rephrase the first sentence below in the form of the second one?

1. There is no chance of her being alive.
2. There is no chance of getting her alive.

Comment: For *approximately* the same meaning, #2 should be *There is no chance of **finding** her alive.* Note that *getting [hold of] her alive* would be more likely if the speaker were, for example, a [bounty hunter](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bounty+hunter) - either saying that he doesn't expect to be able to find/capture the female prisoner alive (***he*** won't "get" her alive), or that he intends to make sure she's dead before delivering the body to the authorities (***they** won't get her alive).

Comment: The meaning of the second sentence is unclear.  It could be taken to mean raising her from the dead.

Answer (score 3):

I think it cannot be paraphrased as such since there is a change in meaning. In the first one it is supposed that she is not alive. There is no possibility. She must be dead. In the second sentence maybe she is alive at the moment but the search for her may last too long and  in the end when we get her (find her) she will have lost her life already. That is what I understand.

Comment: +1 Nice. But there is another context in which the second sentence makes sense. Imagine a bounty hunter who aims to catch the woman, a  fugitive from justice.  "There is no chance of getting her alive" may express the idea that she will never allow herself to be brought to justice.   She'd rather die than surrender.